# iOS cron jobs without server code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is it possible to set (Linux) cron like jobs in iOS apps (any version including iOS 8) that run at set times regardless of whether the app is open or in background mode?

For example, I'd like to run a network GET operation from an iPhone at 11:00 and 23:00. If the job doesn't run because the phone is powered down, that's ok.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to access the underlying cron on an non jailbroken device.

The closest would be `UILocalNotification` - effectively an alert with a specific fire date, or `Background Fetch` in iOS 7.

Background fetch lets your device wake on a *requested* interval to do some network activity. However you're still at the mercy of the system.

http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/

Comment: But what if the app is running in foreground. Only want certain jobs running in background thread.